# Using preg_replace() with the_content filter

Tags: filters, regex

I am trying to append a php query to the end of links from my website to a sponsor site using the_content filter and `preg_replace()`.  I have tested my regex expression on regexr.com and it works also I have used `print_r()` to test that the function is being called but for some reason the links are not being changed in practice.

Here is the code I am having trouble with

```
add_filter('the_content', 'linkAppend');

function linkAppend($content) {
  global $referalString;

  preg_replace('/\/\/(www|launch)?\.?(solarwinds\.com)\/[^"]*/g','$&?cmp='.$referalString, $content);
  return $content;
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction or let me know where I went wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to either assign `$content = preg_replace(...` or just `return preg_replace(...`

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I had multiple problems, @bonger pointed out the first one and then I found and solved issues with the global flag on the regular expression not being valid in php and me not accounting for links without a `/` after the `.com`.  Final fix looks like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'linkAppend');

function linkAppend($content) {
  global $referalString;
  $content = preg_replace('/\/\/(www|launch)?\.?(solarwinds\.com)\/?[^"]*/m','$0?cmp='.$referalString, $content);
  return $content;
}
```